# React native vertical scroll is not working

Tags: react-native, scrollview

I am working on a react native project. Where I need to implement drop-down with an input field. When I type anything in the input field it should filter the dropdown content.

I can't use react-native-dropdown on anything because it placed a mask on the whole screen and I am not able to type anything when the dropdown is open.

So I tried to implement my own drop-down.

```
<View style = {{position:'absolute', zIndex:5, backgroundColor:'red'}}>

              <View style = {[Styles.dropdownView, {display:this.props.display}]}>
              <ScrollView   style={{ top:0, bottom:0}}>
                { listData.map((val, i) => <Text key = {i} > {val} </Text> )}
              </ScrollView>
              </View>

 </View>
```

Every thing is working fine but I am not able to scroll it vertically. Though it's working fine with horizontal scroll.

Please help me to fix this or suggest some other way.

Comment: Try to set height on scrollview or parent view.

Comment: I tried that too but its not working

Comment: What is the top view component? maybe scrollview or listview?

Comment: Yes top view is also a scroll view

Comment: `<View style = {{position:'absolute', zIndex:5, backgroundColor:'red'}}>`
given its position: 'abolute' and your not providing height and width.
Also your using top:0 and bottom:0 without giving position absolute `<ScrollView   style={{ top:0, bottom:0}}>` .Try giving width and height to the parent View and ScrollView and check if its working

Comment: Also remove top:0, bottom:0 from ScrollView

Comment: Thanks Ravi for replying. Actually, the issue was nested scrolling I had to change the implementation to fix it.